# What just happened to my Windows PC? icons don't show; all folders are read-only

Tags: windows-7, permissions, file-permissions, file-attributes

Since yesterday my PC has been behaving oddly. The basic symptoms are:

- Scripts that worked earlier in the day now fail with file/folder permission errors. More specifically, this error in NodeJS (searching for this error shows this to be a file permission issue):

> Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat {{FILE PATH HERE}}

- Every single folder I've checked is marked with a read-only Attribute when I right-click and look at its properties. I don't know whether that was the case before
  [image]
- I can still create and edit files in folders
- File icons no longer show up for many files that used to have them. For instance, PDF, EXE,MP3 and ZIP files

[image]

Something is off, but I don't know what could have triggered it or even what it is. The very first thing I noticed was that a program was unable to save changes to an opened file. I had to delete it and create another with the same name.   I don't even know whether that's related to this.

I've tried restarting the PC.

Comment: Have you checked for malware (virus, trojan, ...)?

Comment: Read-only attribute is actually normal.  Restore your default file association.  Google how to do that

Comment: Rebuild the icon cache? [.PDF icon corrupted on Windows 7](//superuser.com/q/157808)

Comment: Hi @DavidPostill. After posting I saw a different answer which lead me to do just that (delete icon db and restart). It seems to have fixed the issue though I'm still testing.  Don't know why it would interfere with a script running (my first symptom in the OP)

Comment: @Ramhound thanks. The issue wasn't broken file association. The same default programs as always would start and open the files on double-click (eg: Adobe Acrobat would start if I double-click the PDF in my screenshot)